# Circuit for rebooting by pressing momentary switches

Tags: switches, logic-gates

I don't understand the schematics for this rebooting system based on pressing momentary switches. They are the schematics of Flipper Zero. (I am trying to look some schematics online to start understanding them. I am new to electronics.)

[image: SCHEMATICS OF THE BUTTONS]

The Flipper should reboot if BOTH the "Back" and "Left" switches are pressed for 5 seconds. But there is an OR gate and not an AND. Also it should hard reboot if the "Back" switch is pressed for 30 sec.  But, what if I press the "Left" switch for 30 sec? The circuit is similar / somehow identical.
source : https://docs.flipper.net/development/hardware/schematic

Comment: That is a very poor schematic. There are crossing lines and T-junctions with no connecting dots. It's not possible to say what is driving the OR gate inputs.

Comment: Those are "switches", not "buttons" A button is just a piece of plastic.

Comment: There are 14 ambiguous crossed nets in the schematic.  Please add connection dots to show true connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons pull the lines low, and this is using inverse logic. If either of the button inputs is high, then that indicates not pressed, and thus not resetting. Thus it should only pull reset low if neither of the inputs is high.

Or in other words, if gnd is true and 3.3v is false, then by de morgans law, the 'or' gate is actually a "low input and" gate.

Comment: thank you, understood